# C# Label example - What's wrong?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, label

I am learning C# at the moment with a book. The example shows me a code that doesn't work in my VS 2010 with Windows Forms properties. Can somebody help me whats wrong here?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms.Label;

namespace LabelTest
{
  static class CHauptfenster : Form
  {
    Label  labelAusgabe;

    public CHauptfenster()
    {
      Text = "Begruessung";
      Width = 400;
      Height = 250;

      labelAusgabe = new Label();
      labelAusgabe.Height = 30;
      labelAusgabe.Width = 350;
      labelAusgabe.Left = (this.Width / 2) - (labelAusgabe.Width / 2);
      labelAusgabe.Top = 50;
      labelAusgabe.Text = "Hallo Windows!";
      labelAusgabe.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 20);
      labelAusgabe.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
      Controls.Add(labelAusgabe);
    }

  static void Main()
  {
    Application.Run(new CHauptfenster());
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work_ exactly? You get any exception or error message? Unexpected result? You need to be more specific about your problem.

Comment: You never call `InitializeComponent`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, here are a lots of basic mistakes. I took your code and edited and run. try below. I will explain the mistakes.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;


namespace LabelTest
{
    public class CHauptfenster : Form
    {
        public Label labelAusgabe;

        public CHauptfenster()
        {
            Text = "Begruessung";
            Width = 400;
            Height = 250;

            labelAusgabe = new Label();
            labelAusgabe.Height = 30;
            labelAusgabe.Width = 350;
            labelAusgabe.Left = (this.Width / 2) - (labelAusgabe.Width / 2);
            labelAusgabe.Top = 50;
            labelAusgabe.Text = "Hallo Windows!";
            labelAusgabe.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 20);
            labelAusgabe.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            Controls.Add(labelAusgabe);
        }
    }
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
       Application.Run(new CHauptfenster());
    }
}
```

**Mistakes:**

1. There are no Namespace like `Label`.
2. Static Class cannot inherit other class (like Form), they can inherit only objects.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. The thing is that my book is exactly telling me the code I wrote in my answer.

Comment: can you send me any think, that I can see the book?

Comment: What do you mean with "any think" ?

Comment: if its a pdf, then you can send me pdf, if its any online material u can send me the link or if its a hardcopy then u can tell me the book name along with author and publication

Comment: Its a german book called "Visual C# 2008 in 21 Tagen" from Shinja Strasser and Dirk Louis - Site 594/595. I didn't find any google.books or similar where you can see that site.

Comment: yap... I got the book in scribd. but there is only access to 543 pages... sorry buddy... cannot investigate further

Comment: Bummer. But thank you very much for your help!